# Braintree and Kount (GENE version 2.2.3) installation on Magento ver. 1.14.0.1

Tags: api, xml, url, controllers, braintree

I'm trying to configure ENS via a Braintree, Kount, Magento workflow, and  are experiencing errors that i'm unable to diagnose.

**Here's what I'm doing:**
Order # 100096149 | Jan 8, 2018 3:51:07 PM (random order number)

This order number above is in payment review.

I head over to https://awc.test.kount.net/workflow/queue.html and login: Workflow > Suspect Orders.

Then I check the order in question and select the drop down box and mark as approve, leave a comment if necessary and then Submit. After that the order disappears out of the kount menu.

When I go back to magento Sales > Orders I see my order but it still has a "payment review" status.

I believe it's suppose to utilize this frontend URL to locate and parse some order status xml in addition to the api but i get an error page.

*There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 289481254204*

That URL which errors is: https://this.yourstore.com/index.php/braintree/kount_ens/

In their documentation it says "This URL must be publicly accessible for the ENS to function correctly."

I believe this may be the problem. When i check the specific report number, i get this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:20:"Invalid ENS request.";i:1;s:975:"#0 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/code/community/Gene/Braintree/controllers/Kount/EnsController.php(33): Mage::throwException('Invalid ENS

req...')

#1 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Gene_Braintree_Kount_EnsController->indexAction()

#2 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

#3 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#4 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#5 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#6 /var/www/html/ecommerce-us-ca-rev328/index.php(88): Mage::run('usa_en', 'store')

#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/braintree/kount_ens/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:6:"usa_en";}
```

EnsController.php - line 33

```
 // Validate the IP address of the request
        if (!$ens->isValidEnsIp($http->getRemoteAddr())) {
            Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log('Invalid IP for ENS request: ' . $http->getRemoteAddr());
            Mage::throwException('Invalid ENS request.');
        }
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Actions - Here's what I've tried:**

1. I've worked through all the error logs including system.log,
   execption.log and braintree.log ensuring there are no errors or
   restrictions
2. I've whitelisted all IP's and cleared all rules with our firewall to
   ensure there is nothing blocking us there.
3. I've tried using the IP instead of the URL for the ens URL:
   https://exactIpAddress/braintree/kount_ens/
4. Created new API keys
5. Checked user permissions

Need help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ENS error response is normal if you are directly accessing the address, as there isn't an XML or JSON call attaxhed to it.

You may want to ensure that the ENS response URL is publically accessable, and ensure that the URL is listening on port 80 and/or port 443. (Check your firewall setting for that).

Also ensure that your Kount Call-back URL is set properly for your site:
https://yoursite.com/index.php/brain_tree/kount_ens/

That is the best I can offer.